# Import .vcs file into google calendar

Tags: android, google-calendar

I have bunch of .vcs files now i want to import them into google calendar. I googled for solution and i find a way that mentions

> 1. You need to save the .vcs file first into your hard drive ;)
> 2. Go to your Google Calendar page (https://www.google.com/calendar/) - You need to login with your username & password.
> 3. Go to - "Other calendars" on the bottom-left side of the page. Then click the downward arrow at the end of the "Other calendars" menu.
> 4. Then select the "Import calendar".
> 5. A new pop up window will appear. Then just browse to the saved .vcs file and select it. Choose which calendar that you would like to save
>      this new calendar. Then click "Import".

After i followed these steps i get following error

> Processed zero events.
>
> Failed to import events: Unable to process your iCal/CSV file..

Please mention some way to import my .vcs files into google calendar

Comment: FWIW, this method worked without trouble for me.  You probably had invalid VCS files or maybe Google had some kind of internal trouble that has been resolved since then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem yesterday when I was moving many .vcs files from my old mobile to Google Calendar. I found a solution when I was removing some lines from these files. In my case it was the line which begins with "RRULE", e.g.:

```
RRULE:YM1 #0
```

Maybe that line cause error in your case too. All I needed was to remove that line.

Comment: `RRULE:YM1 #0` is a Recurrence Rule (repetition), but an invalid one. This should have generated some kind of error message at the import.
Which program did create such `RRULE` entries?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing "End" to "END" in the file and saving as a .ics. Then do your import steps from above.

This little trick lets you save United Airlines Reservation and other .vcs files to Google Calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to @oskark's Answer I also had to change all entries with the description containing a new line character to make the import work.

1. remove all occurrences of `RRULE:YM1 #0`
2. Remove all newlines `\n` after a `DESCRIPTION` until the next tag begins

---

For example:

```
DTEND:20160328T142300Z
DESCRIPTION;CHARSET=UTF-8;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:some very long
string
LOCATION; ...
```

becomes

```
DTEND:20160328T142300Z
DESCRIPTION;CHARSET=UTF-8;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:some very long string
LOCATION; ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the import failed due to errors in the file. Unfortunately `Failed to import events: Unable to process your iCal/CSV file..` gives not much information.

Check your file before import with some iCal checking tool. Currently I use https://icalendar.org/validator.html which takes files, URLs and entered text. You will get back a detailed list of all errors with pointers to the specification to understand what went wrong (may enough for you to fix it).